# can you replace a video background with an image based on viewport limitations without JS?

Tags: css, html, video, responsive-design

I have applied a video background to the page using the html5 `video` element. Is it possible to replace the video with an image based on viewport limitations without using JavaScript?
My goal is to avoid the video background on mobile devices.

HTML:

```
<video playsinline autoplay muted loop id="DemoReel2018">
<source src="resources/AgsVision_backgroundMovie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

CSS:

```
#DemoReel2018{
position: fixed;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
min-width: 100%; 
min-height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to know about matchmedia https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia

Matchmedia is like css media queries. If your screen has a certain width something happens. In your case your code (in jquery) would look something like this.

```
if (window.matchMedia("(max-width: 480px)").matches) {
  /* Execute this code if t he screen is smaller or equal to 480px (mobile) */
} else {
  /* Desktop */
}
```

I'd recommend putting this jquery code in your **document ready** event.

Now you need to add you Image (preferably below your video) and give it a different id than the one you gave the video.

```
<video playsinline autoplay muted loop id="DemoReel2018">
<source src="resources/AgsVision_backgroundMovie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>

<img id="demoImage" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/01/05/00/20/test-image-3061864_960_720.png" alt="Mobile image">
```

Now just set the image / video "display:none" where you dont want to see it:

```
$("#ID-OF-YOUR-IMAGE").css("display", "none");
```

Now the only thing you need to do is combine these informations and you're done.

Comment: I was actually looking for a solution that would not use JavaScript, but thanks for the solution and I will definitely keep it as an option.

Comment: There is another way of doing it. You could try putting the image behind the video (use position absolute to achieve that) and then use a css media query to set the video display:none on mobile.

Comment: That sounds like a great option, but I believe that if the <source> element’s parent is a media element (video in this case), then it cannot take srcset, sizes, and media as an attribute. At least, that's what I understood from the w3c specifications. I did find a few examples of this usage on other websites but none worked.

Comment: I think it should be possible. Otherwhise try putting a container around the two elements.

Comment: I'm assuming that using a container around the two would involve using JavaScript to obtain the desired limitation. I'm looking for a non-JS solution (if there is any)

Comment: I don't quite get why it shouldn't work with css only. This is my css only (+html of course) fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/e2oaa189/ (it does NOT work in the preview but it would work on a live website). By the way. what's wrong with JQuery/JavaScript?

Comment: Happy to let you know that with a small addition to the syntax (screen AND (min-width=....), your solution will do great.
Nothing wrong with JS. In fact, I'm very enthusiastic to start using it (once I learn it). REALLY appreciate the help.